# Two EOF required to actually end reading from terminal

Tags: c, windows, input, eof

I have been trying to understand how `EOF` works. In my code (on Windows) invoking `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>) doesn't work the first time and I have to provide two `EOF` for it to actually stop reading input. Also, the first `EOF` gets read as some garbage character which gets displayed when I print the input. (We can see the garbage characters being display at the end in the output provided).

**This is my code:-**

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define Max 1000

int main()
{
    char c, text[Max];
    int i = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        text[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    printf("\nEntered Text: \n");
    puts(text);

    return 0;
}
```

**My Output:**

[image: My Output:]

**I have this doubt:-**

Why are two `EOF`s being required? and how do I prevent the first one from being read (as some garbage) and stored as part of my input?

Comment: Fyi, you're not terminating your string before sending it to `puts`, and therefore invoking *undefined behavior*. That is more than anything the reason you're getting "some garbage character" when printing. There should be a `text[i] = 0;` immediately *after* the while-loop closes.

Comment: Have you tried entering the first  ^Z on a new line, rather than immediately after the '?'?  Also, what happens when you single step through this in your debugger?  Watching the value in `c` may provide a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried making the changes you suggested, but it still doesn't solve the issue.Anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Pardon me, but I simply do not believe that specific change doesn't solve the issue of "some garbage character" . Regarding the action of requiring two ctrl-Z for simulating EOF, that topic is covered by multiple questions on this site if you search for them.  In the case of a non-empty input line, the first ctrl-Z is to flush the current line buffer, the second is to trip EOF. For a blank, new line, you *should* only have to enter it once.

Comment: @dgnuff entering the ^Z in new line does indeed solve the problem.So thanks for suggesting it.But, then again it introduces an extra new line character.(which I know is invisible and wouldn't have an impact here, but it certain complex scenarios may cause problems when manipulating the string)

Comment: @WhozCraig I'll look into it again. Thanks.

Comment: In my test (WIndows 10 / VS2017), it does not require two ^Z, but it does require <newline>^Z<newline>. That is to say if the ^Z is preceded by anything other then <newline> it is ignored.

Comment: @abhinavk WhozCraig was not making a suggestion to solve your problem, merely pointing out another issue - and the cause of the garbage.If it was a solution he'd have posted an answer not a comment.  Comments are not answers.

Comment: @Clifford the first ctrl-Z isn't ignored, it flushes the current line if entered after input, but without an immediately-preceding line flush (typically a CR, LF, both, depending on the system). If the input is `Hello World` with *no* enter/return following, ctrl-Z is required twice; one to flush the line (without a newline trailing), and once to light EOF. If `Hello World <enter>` is done, then *nothing else*, only one ctrl-z should be required.

Comment: @Clifford It's my first time posting, so still working  to understand the common conventions.But, yea i know it wasn't a solution, didn't mean to imply it in any way.

Comment: @Clifford: "*it does seem to discard the remainder of the line*" I exactly noticed this. Unfortunately only after I commented. This comment is gone in the mean while. Please excuse.

Comment: @WhozCraig ; My tests corroborate that;  it is not ignored; I should have said "_does not generate an EOF_". perhaps?  I believe it is a CP/M hangover where files were composed of fixed length records, so a ^Z in the middle of a record, was used to indicate the end of valid data for files that were not an exact multiple of the record length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution fixes the Ctrl+Z problem and the garbage output and also blocks a buffer overrun.  I have commented the changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Max 1000
#define CTRL_Z 26           // Ctrl+Z is ASCII/ANSI 26

int main()
{
    int c ;                  // getchar() returns int
    char text[Max + 1] ;     // +1 to acommodate terminating nul
    int i = 0;

    while( i < Max &&                 // Bounds check
           (c = getchar()) != EOF && 
           c != CTRL_Z )              // Check for ^Z when not start of input buffer
    {
        text[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    text[i] = 0 ;        // Terminate string after last added character

    printf( "\nEntered Text:\n" );
    puts( text );

    return 0;
}
```

The reason for this behavior is somewhat arcane, but end-of-file is not the same as Ctrl-Z.  The console generates an end-of-file causing `getchar()` to return EOF (-1) if and only if the console input buffer is empty, otherwise it inserts the ASCII SUB (26) character into the stream.  The use of SUB was originally to do with MS-DOS compatibility with the even earlier CP/M operating system.  In particular CP/M files were composed of fixed length records, so a ^Z in the middle of a record, was used to indicate the end of valid data for files that were not an exact multiple of the record length. In the console, the SUB is readable rather than generating an EOF if it is not at the start of the input buffer and all characters after the SUB are discarded.  It is all a messy hangover from way-back.

Answer (score 2):

Control-Z is only recognized as `EOF` when at the start of a new line.  Therefore, if you want to detect it in the middle of a line, you'll need to do so yourself.

So change this line:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

to this:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != CTRL_Z)
```

and then add:

```
#define CTRL_Z ('Z' & 0x1f)
```

at the top of your program.

You may still need to type a <kbd>return</kbd> after the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> to get the buffered input to be read by the program, but it should discard everything after the ^Z.

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: I'd rather not be cited - at least not with reference to a temporary comment that may be delete - it may serve later only to confuse.  You are welcome to use or repeat information in my comments without acknowledgement.

Comment: @afk yes, but I then mistyped when transcribing. :/

Comment: @Clifford Edited to respect your comment.  For the record, I'm a great believer in credit where credit is due. ;)

Comment: For the record; my answer was inspired by yours.

Comment: Please excuse, I was completely wrong. Lets clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the type of `c` to `int` as `EOF` can be a negative number and commonly it is defined as `-1`. `char` might or might not be able to store `-1`. Also, do not forget to end the string with `\0` before passing it to `puts`.

Comment: I completely  agree with this. `getchar()` returns `int`, and the receptor of said-same should be likewise. It doesn't solve the other problems, nor answer the question, but none-the-less it's note worthy.

Comment: Answers that say "try..." are not answers - unless you know it works.  I tested it and it does not solve the problem.  The point is valid `getchar()` returns an int and EOF cannot be represented in a `char`, but that is worthy of a comment only, not an answer.

Comment: The question was why two EOFs are required - the answer is that they aren't. And it certainly isn't stored in the `text` array. With these changes IMO it's a perfectly valid C code (until `i < Max`) so it's out of C's realm and it's rather a question about ^D or platform peculiarities.

Comment: @GiedriusStatkevičius : Except the Ctrl+Z _is_ stored in the input buffer and returned as ASCII 26 (SUB) if the ^Z is not at the start of the input buffer. It is true that EOF is not buffered, it is generated.  The point is that you are proposing an untested solution and it does not work - I know because I tested it. This is specific to Windows (and historically MS-DOS) and somewhat arcane. ^D is a POSIX console EOF; Windows does not conform to that.  My point stands - he can "try" your suggestion, but it will fail - so this is clearly not an answer.  It is not incorrect, just not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The logic that Windows terminals follow with regard to `^Z` in keyboard input (at least in their default configuration) is as follows:

- The <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> combination itself does not cause the input line buffer to get pushed to the waiting application. This key combination simply generates `^Z` character in the input buffer. You have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish that line buffer and send it to the application.

  You can actually keep entering additional characters after `^Z` and before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- If the input line does not begin with `^Z`, but contains `^Z` inside, then the application will receive that line up to *and including* the first `^Z` character (read as `\x1A` character). The rest of the input is discarded.

  E.g. if you type in

  ```
  Hello^Z World^Z123
  ```

  and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> your C program will actually read `Hello\x1A` sequence. EOF condition will not arise.
- If the input line begins with `^Z`, the whole line is discarded and EOF condition is set.

  E.g. if you input

  ```
  ^ZHello World
  ```

  and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> your program will read nothing and immediately detect EOF.

This is the behavior you observe in your experiments. Just keep in mind that the result of `getchar()` should be received into an `int` variable, not a `char` variable.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. Ty.